# Is it possible to add/update a JSP to a war file with the jar utility?

Tags: jar, zip, war

The `jar` utility certainly has a `-u` or `--update` argument that seems to be related to my objective of updating the JSP files inside a war file. However, there is no `-a` or `--add` option, so I supposed there is no easy way of adding/updating the contents of a `.war` file without going through a manual cycle of unpacking and repacking everything.

Is there a way of doing this from the command-line without unpacking the `.war` file?

Comment: JARs and WARs are basically just ZIP files with a different file extension and a specific layout of files in that zip. If you can't do something with the `jar` tool, you can use a zip tool to do it (as long as it isn't a signed JAR).

Comment: I’m pretty sure `jar -u` will do what you want.  It certainly can add files to a .jar or .war file.

Comment: Thank you VGR. Yes, the `-u` option can also add files selecting the target directory with the -C option

Comment: You can use any ZIP utility like PKZIP to add files to the archive.